# How to get all the classes my application load in JAVA

Tags: java

How to get all the classes loaded by my application running in integrated weblogic server . I used  java -verbose:class and created a javaagent that returns .getAllLoadedClasses() using Instrumentation package . Both returns a large set of results mainly from packages java.* and sun.* but no class from my app was present in the output. How to get the classes loaded by my app. I am a beginner. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something with following

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections(ClasspathHelper
                          .forClass(Object.class),new SubTypesScanner(false));
Set<String> classList =reflections.
                         getStore().getSubTypesOf(Object.class.getName())
```

FYI: [Reflections](https://code.google.com/p/reflections/)

Comment: I used the code inside a class say client.popup and inside it I call another class apps.Calculate , but above code doesn't display either of the classes , but instead show all java.* , com.* etc.. classes. Did I do anything wrong or is it not possible with this.

Answer (score 0):

You might try to experiment with `java.lang.ClassLoader`. This class has an internal attribute `classes` of type `Vector`. If you use reflection then you can access the loaded classes of its classloader-instance only. And of course you can also go up the ClassLoader-hierarchy to ask the parents of application classloader.